# Is a tree a series parallel graph?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

In ON THE STABLE SET POLYTOPE OF A SERIES-PARALLEL GRAPH from A.R. MAHJOUB (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01580723) it is written:

> A homeomorph of K4 is a graph obtained from K 4 when its edges are
> subdivided into paths by inserting new nodes of degree two. Graphs
> which contain no homeo- morph of K4 as a subgraph are called
> series-parallel graphs [4].

From this definition i would say yes.

But from the definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_graph

i would say no.

What i am missing here?

Comment: Quoting directly from the Wikipedia article: "2-connected series-parallel graphs are characterised by having no subgraph homeomorphic to K4." The property of being "2-connected" is needrf it seems.

Comment: The answer is they are using different definitions. The first one contains more graphs. One needs to check in each paper which is used.